# Start Tomcat with Maven Cargo without stop when Maven is finish

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-cargo

Is ist possible to Start a Tomcat with Maven without stopping Tomcat after Maven has finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look possible.  Look at the plugin documentation [here](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin).

> cargo:start  : will automatically shut down as soon as the parent Maven
>   instance quits
>   cargo:run : Start a container and wait for the user to
>   press CTRL + C to stop

Comment: Why they are not logging SHUT DOWN log message if they are explicitly shutting down the container? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it **is** possible. You need to create Maven sub-project and start it with `maven-antrun-plugin` as a background process.